# Getting empty DocumentSnapshot when querying new collection with a document name

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I very recently created two new collections in my Firestore project and inserted documents in both of these.
When I try to retrieve a document from these collections from my Python app, querying for the document's name through very basic code, I'm getting an empty DocumentSnapshot, with .exists attribute == False.

If I use the same code to address an older collection/ document in my project, I successfully gets a DocumentSnapshot with .exists == True and the document data.

The code is so basic and common that it's honestly a loss of time to look at it, but here it is...

```
from google.cloud import firestore
db = firestore.Client()
doc_name = u'MzZrWvmaqTtkDxus5pF8'

doc_ref = db.collection(u'new_collection').document(doc_name)
doc = doc_ref.get()
   if doc.exists:
      print(f'Document data: {doc.to_dict()}')
   else:
      print(u'No such document!')
print(doc)
```

On the new collections, this returns:

```
No such document!
<google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_document.DocumentSnapshot object at 0x3edeadfccbd0>
```

I'm using Firestore in native mode from a Python app. Using the latest version of the google-cloud-firestore lib for Python.

It would be great if someone with a Cloud Firestore project could make a quick try at querying a newly created collection to get a sense of whether this is a widespread issue or not. I already opened an issue tracker ticket with Google Cloud but it's a very random chance at getting assistance.

thank you!

Comment: Update: new collection created today works properly. But the two previous ones still fail. Looks like they were not properly instantiated.

Comment: when you browse the firestore in GCP are you able to see this collections and documents? Did you get any error during the creation of those?

Comment: Yes seeing them displayed as would any other, and no error at all during creation.

Comment: could you share the collections that gave the error and one that did not so that is possible to compare and see what happened?

Comment: 1 of the two is now working. 1 still has the same issue (happens to be the one created manually in the web app, while the other was created programatically by creating a first document). What exactly would you like me to share? Structure-wise they are super basic collections, nothing fancy.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the structure of the failed collection at least to try to detect anything that might have caused, but at this point, and since this collection was created manually as you said, it might be a better idea to simply delete it and recreate it.